# webpack require every file in directory

Tags: javascript, webpack

This is my file structure

```
-main.js
-SomeDir
   -fileA.js
   -fileB.js
```

What should I do if I want to load (inside `main.js`) every file in `someDir` without specifying the file names -

something like: `require(./someDir/*.js)` ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Solution:

```
var req = require.context("../someDir", true, /^(.*\.(js$))[^.]*$/igm);
req.keys().forEach(function(key){
    req(key);
});
// or just: req.keys().forEach(req)
```

#### extra:

regex to match `js` but ignore `test.js`

`/^(?!.*test.js)((.*\.(js\.*))[^.]*$)/igm)`

Comment: I got an error when using this approach, any suggestion? Thanks. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1635

Comment: @NickMcCurdy Isn't it the other way round? Webpack 1 and Webpack 2 [both](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) [support this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context), but it wouldn't work without Webpack... or do I miss something here?

Comment: Sorry I was totally wrong, this was webpack syntax I was unaware of. Deleting my comment.

Comment: What's the ES6 version for this require?

Comment: Does anyone know how you'd require multiple directories with this method?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible, even recursively in the folder hierarchy

Here's a sample:

```
var context = require.context('./', true, /\.(html)$/);
var files={};

context.keys().forEach((filename)=>{
  console.log(filename);
  files[filename] = context(filename);
});
console.log(files); //you have file contents in the 'files' object, with filenames as keys
```

And a live demo here (open up devtools to see the generated object)

http://www.webpackbin.com/Vy6AwkWrz

In your case the first line would be

```
var context = require.context('./SomeDir', false, /\.js$/);
```

Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html#require-context

Comment: Just a heads up, those links are out of date

Answer (score 6):

One approach could be to create an index.js file in SomeDir location and in that file:

```
var req = require.context('./', true, /\.js$/);
req([]);
```

Then in main.js:

```
require('./SomeDir');
```

or

```
require('./SomeDir/index.js');
```

or even

```
import something from "./SomeDir";
```

Comment: What's the difference between `req([])` and invoking `req` on each key like the accepted answer does?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module ''.` at the line `req([])`, why doesn't it work?

Comment: @JianWeihang well this is 3yrs old, apis change.. it worked with webpack 1 and 2 if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack5 cause "webpack-context-dup-keys"
[Solution here](https://github.com/hkennyv/next-theme-terminal/commit/391975cb9f09cfa58f801386cc8a405cbc2e8831)
We have to use below /./.*.md$/
e.g.

```
 let ctxWrong   = require.context("../content/posts", true, /\.md$/);
 let ctxCorrect = require.context("../content/posts", true, /\.\/.*\.md$/);
```

[Please look at issue here](https://github.com/uditalias/webpack-context-dup-keys/blob/master/src/index.js)