# React Import Icons / Images in bulk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, webpack

I have 100's of Icons and Images to be imported. Is there any way to eliminate writing so many import statements at the top of the page? I was thinking to write  a import statements in a separate file and embed that at the top.

```
import basicAmenitiesIcon from '../../../../images/icons/wifi-sign.png';
import parkingIcon from '../../../../images/icons/parking.png';
...
```

Any other way of solving it? I'm using webpack and here is the config:

```
{
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    loaders: [
        'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
        'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
    ]
}
```

Comment: why do not you  use font image..  that will faster and no need to right import for each and every icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is posible, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410938/646156

```
var context = require.context('../../../../images/icons', true, /\.(png)$/);
var files={};

context.keys().forEach((filename)=>{
  files[filename] = context(filename);
});
console.log(files); //you have file contents in the 'files' object, with filenames as keys
```

Comment: and may I add there's a similar accepted answer on the question I referenced you to

Comment: Was waiting for this. Thank you.