# specifying a complete sub directory in webpack 2 entry

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I have a webpack 2 configuration as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: [
        "./app.ts",
        "./tab.ts",
        "./client/clientService.ts",
        "./client/clientSearchComponent.ts",
        "./infrastructure/messageComponent.ts",
        "./infrastructure/typeaheadComponent.ts",
        "./url.ts"],
    output: {
        filename: "./wwwroot/js/admin/admin.js"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    }
};
```

This is imported into a gulp task as follows...

```
gulp.task("admin:js",
    function (done) {
        var configuration = require(path.join(__dirname, config.js, "admin/webpack.config.js").toString());
        webpack(configuration).run(reportWebpackResults(done));
    });
```

I am finding that I have to specify each component in `entry[...]`.

How do I specify globs, they don't seem to work out of the box.

```
entry: [
    "./client/**/*.ts", // module not found...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a glob library like [globule](https://github.com/cowboy/node-globule). `globule.find` returns an array of the files. So you can use it as the entry:

```
entry: globule.find("./client/**/*.ts")
```

If you want to include other entry points as well you can combine them by spreading the returned array:

```
entry: [
    './other/entry.js'
    ...globule.find("./client/**/*.ts")
]
```

Or use any other way of combining the arrays (e.g. [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)).

Alternatively you can use a single entry that imports everything you need with the help of [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) as shown in the question [webpack require every file in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891458/webpack-require-every-file-in-directory).

```
const req = require.context('./client/', true, /\.ts$/);
req.keys().forEach(req);
```