# What does "**/*" in app.json or package.json mean?

Tags: json, regex, react-native, expo, package.json

I'm building a React Native app using Expo. In my `app.json` there as a key:

```
"assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
```

I know [this key expects a file path](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/offline-support/#bundle-your-assets-inside-your-standalone-binary) as its value. But what does `"**/*"` mean? I have my `assets/` folder an the same level as `app.json` and in it there are three folders called `animations/`, `images/` and `fonts/`. Will they be covered by that value?

Comment: You can try `ls **/*` to check which directories are covered but yes, the three folders you mentioned above will be included.

Comment: @Dan If I do `ls src/**/*.test.js` no files are found. If I do `ls src/**/*` only the files in folders and subfolders are found (including the ones that end on `.test.js`), but the `src/` folders direct files (`src/App.test.js`) are left out. Extra weird that `src/**/*` finds `.test.js` files, but `src/**/*.test.js` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual this `**/*` means all folders and all sub folders are consider by some script.

Maybe this Q/A will help you :

[Q/A how-to-load-all-files-in-a-directory-using-webpack-without-require-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29421409/how-to-load-all-files-in-a-directory-using-webpack-without-require-statements)

also

[Q/A specifying-a-complete-sub-directory-in-webpack-2-entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076133/specifying-a-complete-sub-directory-in-webpack-2-entry)

Most ussualy used by webpack etc.