# pass parameter to variable which assigned require.context

Tags: javascript, webpack

When `require.context` of webpack is assigned to variable,
how this variable can work receiveing `parameter`, like 'key'?
For example,(in webpack document)

```
var context = require.context('components', true, /\.html$/);

// this 'context' variable receive parameter 'localA'
var context = require.context('locales', true, /\.json$/, 'lazy');
context('localeA').then((locale) => {
  // do something with locale
});
```

In this code,
I can't understand why `context` variable can receive `parameter` 'localeA'.
I looked in webpack documents, but I couldn't find how variable which is assigned to `require.context` can receive the parameter.

See another example...

```
var req = require.context("../someDir", true, /^(.*\.(js$))[^.]*$/igm);
req.keys().forEach(function(key){
    req(key);
});
// or just: req.keys().forEach(req)
```

[webpack require every file in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891458/webpack-require-every-file-in-directory)

the var `req` already returned `context` which fits conditions specified in parameters.
then, why this code recall 'req(key)' with 'key' parameter which represents element of array(context) agian?
Does this code mean => require.context(element of context = each file)?
I can't understand this recall either..

- In summary, my question is..

1. How variable which is assignd to `require.context` can accept parameter.
   in webpack document, `require.context` can accept 4 parameter,
   =>

```
require.context(
  (directory: String),
  (includeSubdirs: Boolean) /* optional, default true */,
  (filter: RegExp) /* optional, default /^\.\/.*$/, any file */,
  (mode: String) /* optional, 'sync' | 'eager' | 'weak' | 'lazy' | 'lazy-once', default 'sync' */
);
```

but in the conde i can't understand,
the parameter which is sent to variable(is assigned to 'require.context') is `key (element of context array)`

2. why they recall `require.cnotext` in `require.context.keys().foreach()`,
   `var req = require.context()` already returned context array(files fit conditions),then why this code repeats require.context(key) in foreach() block?

```
var req = require.context("../someDir", true, /^(.*\.(js$))[^.]*$/igm);
// => return context array


req.keys().forEach(function(key){
    req(key);
// => means 'require.context(key)?
// why repeat require.context(each file)?
});
// or just: req.keys().forEach(req)
```

Please help me to understand this..